# Is there a reason my program ends before running my for loop?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist

In my programming class I was asked to make a list of enrolling students with information inside each one, and display all entered students with an average off their grades and if they were admitted to the school or not. everything works fine except when I get to my for loop at the end of the program to display the info of each student and their average, the program simply ends before displaying any info on the students and gives no error messages.

Please help!!

Main Class:

```
public class MainStudent {
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    
    String FullName;
    String answer;
    
    System.out.println("Welcome! Please enroll your students");
    System.out.println("");
    
    
    do {
        Student student = new Student();
        
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the first name of the student");
        student.setFirstName(scan.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the last name of the student");
        student.setLastName(scan.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        FullName = student.getFirstName() + " " +  student.getLastName();
        Boolean validation = false;
        
        while (validation == false) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the ID of " + FullName);
            
            try {
            student.setID(scan.nextInt());
            
            validation = true;
            
        }
        
        catch(Exception e) {
            
            System.out.println("please enter only numbers");
            System.out.println("");
            validation = false;
            scan.next();
        }
        
        }
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the gender of " + FullName);
        student.setGender(scan.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the age of " + FullName);
        student.setAge(scan.nextInt());
        
        if (student.getAge() > 17) {
            
        do {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please enter the first score of " + FullName);
            try {
                student.setScore1(scan.nextInt());
                if (student.getScore1() > 100 || student.getScore1() < 0) {
                    System.out.println("please enter a positive number below 100");
                    validation = false;
                    
                }
                else {
                    validation = true;
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            catch (Exception e) {
                
                System.out.println("Please only enter numbers");
                validation = false;
                scan.next();
            }
            
        }
        while (validation == false);
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the second score of " + FullName);
            try {
                student.setScore2(scan.nextInt());
                
                if (student.getScore2() > 100 || student.getScore2() < 0) {
                    System.out.println("please enter a positive number below 100");
                    validation = false;
                    
                }
                else {
                    validation = true;
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            catch (Exception e) {
                
                System.out.println("Please only enter numbers");
                validation = false;
                scan.next();
            }
            
        }
        while (validation == false);
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the third score of " + FullName);
            try {
                student.setScore3(scan.nextInt());
                if (student.getScore3() > 100 || student.getScore3() < 0) {
                    System.out.println("please enter a positive number below 100");
                    validation = false;
                    
                }
                else {
                    validation = true;
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            catch (Exception e) {
                
                System.out.println("Please only enter numbers");
                validation = false;
                scan.next();
            }
            
        }
        while (validation == false);

        
        System.out.println("");
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the fourth score of " + FullName);
            try {
                student.setScore4(scan.nextInt());
                if (student.getScore4() > 100 || student.getScore4() < 0) {
                    System.out.println("please enter a positive number below 100");
                    validation = false;
                    
                }
                else {
                    validation = true;
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            catch (Exception e) {
                
                System.out.println("Please only enter numbers");
                validation = false;
                scan.next();
            }
             
        }
        while (validation == false);
    }
        
        
        
        
        
        else {
            System.out.println("You can not enroll a student under the age of 18");
            
            student.setScore1(0);
            student.setScore2(0);
            student.setScore3(0);
            student.setScore4(0);
        }
        
        
        System.out.println("Do you want to register another student? \n Answer with Y/N");
         answer = scan.next();
         
        
        
        }
        while (answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y"));
        

    
        
            for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        System.out.println("Name: " + students.get(i).getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Age: " + students.get(i).getAge() );
        System.out.println("Gender: " + students.get(i).getGender());
        System.out.println("Scored Average: " + students.get(i).Average(i, i, i, i));
        System.out.println(students.get(i).Enrolled(i));
        System.out.println("*******************************");
            }
        
        
        

    scan.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Please, apply text/code formatting options correctly to your post.

Answer (score 1):

The loop doesn't run because you aren't actually adding anything to the array list called "students". You might want to start adding stuff inside that list inside the do-while loops, so that `students.size()` is not equal to 0.